# Electronic keyboard emits a high pitch whining noise

Tags: keyboard

I bought this keyboard second hand, it's a pretty cheap generic plastic keyboard. It was demoed to me briefly and seemed ok. But when I took it home I realised there's quite a high pitched whine coming from the speakers.

I plugged some headphones in but the same problem (only now through the headphones).

I've tried attaching a ground loop isolator to the headphone port, and tried a different AC adapter, but neither fixed it.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Take it to an electronics repair shop. This sort of thing is impossible to diagnose over the internet.

Comment: Worth a shot, it's going to the landfill then

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that this applies to your situation, but I've noticed that digital instruments sometimes broadcast a high pitch signal which can be picked up and amplified by nearby amps. It's really guessing on my part, but I'd be inclined to open up the casing and try to determine if some shielding is missing around the amplifier circuitry designed to eliminate an issue such as this. It might be a simple fix, or maybe not.

Comment: Gave it a go, what an unbelievable amount of screws! Couldn't see anything wrong, did a ton of poking about, so I'm afraid it's a lost cause. Thanks though!